# Triggering spellcheck after attribute change

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, spell-checking

I have a contenteditable div with spellcheck set to false. I have a button that when clicked, changes the spellcheck attribute to true, but the spellcheck won't kick in until I click inside the div. I have tried triggering events for click, focus, blur, change etc. on the div, and nothing causes the red lines to appear. This is in old jQuery 1.8 (legacy app). is there a trick to this?

```
$('.spellcheck').live('click', function() {
    $('#editor').attr('spellcheck', true);
    $('#editor').click();
    $('#editor').focus();
    $('#editor').blur();
    $('#editor').change();
});
```

I have also wrapped the events in a 1 second setTimeout to get past any asynchronous race conditions, but no luck.

HTML Part:

```
<div id="editor" class="editor" contenteditable spellcheck="false"></div>
<button class="spellcheck">Check Spelling</button>
```

- this isn't really a problem of contenteditable, it happens on a normal div as well.

Comment: Can you provide this html part as well please ?

Comment: Added HTML to the original post

Comment: tshimkus, read my post. This is jQuery 1.8.

Comment: Also, that is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: You may wish to consider the secondary unintended effects of your comments.  If your goal is to rile up @tshimkus, congratulations, you've succeeded. If your goal is to try to find a solution and to convince others that you're worthy of their efforts to help you, then your comments above, might not help you achieve this.

Comment: The classname on the button is 'spellcheck' - so is the attribute I am trying to change. I guess I don't understand how you don't understand that clicking on a button and firing that code above will change the spellcheck attribute from false to true? It's like... basic javascript. And it works, it does change the attribute... it just doesn't fire the actual spellchecking to start working (showing red lines under words) until after you click the button and ALSO click on the text.

Answer (score 1):

Click the button, it adds the `spellcheck` attribute and then sets focus to the `#editor` div. Spellcheck is active and underlining misspelled words.

Here it is in **jQuery 1.8.1**:

```js
$('.spellcheck').click( function () {
    $('#editor').attr('spellcheck', true);
    $('#editor').focus();
});
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="editor" contenteditable spellcheck="false">
   somme mispellled wordds
</div>
<button class="spellcheck">Check Spelling</button>
```

Here's the same code in a different snippet, this one running **jQuery 1.2.3**:

```js
$('.spellcheck').click( function () {
    $('#editor').attr('spellcheck', true);
    $('#editor').focus();
});
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="editor" contenteditable spellcheck="false">
   somme mispellled wordds
</div>
<button class="spellcheck">Check Spelling</button>
```

Comment: It's so odd it doesn't work in our app... the exact same code, we tried that before I even added this question. Nothing will trigger the red lines until you manually click it.

Comment: Here's something that's weird... if I enter "T‍est 2asas asasas asasas" w/o quotes into the contenteditable div and click the spellcheck button, it works. But if I enter "Thiis is teh wroong speling" it does not work until I click into he div. I set lang="en" in the contenteditable div #editor.